# Use promises for multiple node requests

Tags: node.js, express, promise

With the `request` library, is there a way to use promises to simplify this callback?

```
  var context = {};

  request.get({
    url: someURL,
  }, function(err, response, body) {

    context.one = JSON.parse(body);

    request.get({
      url: anotherURL,
    }, function(err, response, body) {
      context.two = JSON.parse(body);

      // render page
      res.render('pages/myPage');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where do `someURL` and `anotherURL` come from, does the second request actually depend on the first one? Also, where is `context` used? And why don't you handle any errors?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using the Bluebird promises library.  This serializes the two requests and accumulates the results in the `context` object and rolls up error handling all to one place:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});

var context = {};
request.getAsync(someURL).spread(function(response, body) {
    context.one = JSON.parse(body);
    return request.getAsync(anotherURL);
}).spread(response, body)
    context.two = JSON.parse(body);
    // render page
    res.render('pages/myPage');
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

---

And, if you have multiple URLs, you can use some of Bluebirds other features like `Promise.map()` to iterate an array of URLs:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"), {multiArgs: true});

var urlList = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
Promise.map(urlList, function(url) {
    return request.getAsync(url).spread(function(response,body) {
        return [JSON.parse(body),url];
    });
}).then(function(results) {
     // results is an array of all the parsed bodies in order
}).catch(function(err) {
     // handle error here
});
```

Or, you could create a helper function to do this for you:

```
// pass an array of URLs
function getBodies(array) {
    return Promise.map(urlList, function(url) {
        return request.getAsync(url).spread(function(response.body) {
            return JSON.parse(body);
        });
    });
});

// sample usage of helper function
getBodies(["url1", "url2", "url3"]).then(function(results) {
    // process results array here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: Added a couple more examples.

Comment: @userpassword - I had to fix up your edit.  I'm not sure why you changed the bluebird library in my answer from `Promise` which it is declared to be in my code to `bluebird`.   I did accept your addition of `multiArgs` which is a change Bluebird made in 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would implement chained Promises.

```js
var request = require("request");

var someURL = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/';
var anotherURL = 'http://ip.jsontest.com/';

function combinePromises(context){
  return Promise.all(
    [someURL, anotherURL].map((url, i)=> {

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        try{

          request.get({
            url: url,
          }, function(err, response, body) {

            if(err){
              reject(err);
            }else{
              context[i+1] = JSON.parse(body);
              resolve(1); //you can send back anything you want here
            }

          });

        }catch(error){
          reject(error);
        }

      });

    })
  );
}

var context = {"1": "", "2": ""};
combinePromises(context)
.then(function(response){

  console.log(context);
  //render page
  res.render('pages/myPage');
  
}, function(error){
  //do something with error here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with native `Promises`. It's good to understand the guts.

> This here is known as the "Promise Constructor Antipattern" as pointed out by @Bergi in the comments. Don't do this. Check out the better method below.

```
var contextA = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  request('http://someurl.com', function(err, response, body) {
    if(err) reject(err);
    else {
      resolve(body.toJSON());
    }
  });
});

var contextB = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  request('http://contextB.com', function(err, response, contextB) {
    if(err) reject(err);
    else {
      contextA.then(function(contextA) {
         res.render('page', contextA, contextB);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The nifty trick here, and I think by using raw promises you come to appreciate this, is that `contextA` resolves once and then we have access to it's resolved result. This is, we *never* make the above request to `someurl.com`, but still have access to `contextA`'s JSON.

So I can conceivable create a `contextC` and reuse the JSON without having to make another request. `Promises` always only resolve *once*. You would have to take that anonymous *executor* function out and put it in a `new Promise` to refresh that data.

Bonus note:

This executes `contextA` and `contextB` in parallel, but will do the final computation that needs both contexts when both `A` & `B` are resolved.

> Here's my new stab at this.

The main problem with the above solution is none of the promises are *reusable* and they are not *chained* which is a key feature of Promises.

However, I still recommend `promisifying` your `request` library yourself and abstaining from adding another dependency to your project. Another benefit of `promisifying` yourself is you can write your own `rejection` logic. This is important if you're working with a particular `API` that sends `error` messages in the body. Let's take a look:

```
//Function that returns a new Promise. Beats out constructor anti-pattern.
const asyncReq = function(options) { 
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  request(options, function(err, response, body) {
   //Rejected promises can be dealt with in a `catch` block.
   if(err) {
    return reject(err);
   } 
   //custom error handling logic for your application.
   else if (hasError(body)) {
    return reject(toError(body));
   }
   // typically I just `resolve` `res` since it contains `body`.
   return resolve(res);
  }
 });
};

asyncReq(urlA)
.then(function(resA) {
  //Promise.all is the preferred method for managing nested context.
  return Promise.all([resA, asyncReq(urlB)]);
})
.then(function(resAB) {
  return render('page', resAB[0], resAB[1]);
})
.catch(function(e) {
  console.err(e);
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [promise constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [request-promise](https://npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library to do this. In your case, you could have something like this, where you chain your requests.

```
request
    .get({ url: someURL })
    .then(body => {
        context.one = JSON.parse(body);

        // Resolves the promise
        return request.get({ url: anotherURL });
    })
    .then(body => {
        context.two = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render('pages/myPage');
    })
    .catch(e => {
        //Catch errors
        console.log('Error:', e);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest is to use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) library. You can also use use a promise library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) and use its `promisify` functions to convert the `request` callback API to a promise API, though you may need to write your own promisify function as `request` does not use the standard callback semantics. Lastly, you can just make your own promise wrapper, using either native promises or bluebird.

If you're starting fresh, just use request-promise. If you're refactoring existing code, I would just write a simple wrapper for `request` using bluebird's `spread` function.